# estimating the frame rate

Tags: frame-rate

I'm developing an slightly animated application (in c++ with opengl). For that, I need to know the framerate the system is capable of. What I now do is calculate the framerate for the last display-action and then average that with the history.
This works slightly: the average rate is still rather jumpy.
This problem must have been solved at least once (e.g. file copy progress dialogs), so I was thinking: would it be helpfull to apply a low pass filter? What values should I use then? My guess is that I should remove all frequencies above 60Hz or so? (my monitor refreshes at 60Hz rate)

Comment: Tried the suggestion by bazkie_bumpercar and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's weird that the average frame rate is jumpy, unless you disabled vsync (okay, i guess you did, since you get frequencies above your refresh rate in the first place ;))

just a hunch: maybe you should get the second [quartile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile) (= the median) of the history over x frames (experiment with x ;)) instead of the average :)

Comment: the framerate is jumpy because the output-routines differ each time in what they output. i like that median idea, would indeed reduce the influence of spikes